# How do I make a collision detection with screen width and height in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision-detection

So I am making a game and I need the collision with screen width and height but I don't know how to achieve this.

I have tried doing this:

```
if rect1.right.colliderect(screen_width):
    rect1.x = 50
    rect1.y = 270
```

and this:

```
if rect1.x >= screen_width:
   print("Collision!")
```

but both methods do not work. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Given that your display surface is named `screen`, you can get a `Rect` that describes your screen with `get_rect()` (like you can do on any other `Surface`), like

```
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
```

So to check if your `Rect` `rect1` is still inside the screen or not, you can use the [`contains`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.contains) method:

```
if not screen_rect.contains(rect1):
    print('rect1 out of screen')
```

You can also prevent `rect1` from moving out of screen by simply using [`clamp_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip), e.g. in your main loop do this:

```
rect1.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
```

and `rect1` will never leave the screen.

Comment: Thank you so much now I can finish my game

Answer (score 0):

When I put this function inside my player class, you could just use the line inside the function, it just creates the rectangle first and then it detects the collision

```py
    def collision(self, obj, window):
        return pygame.draw.rect(window, red, (self.x, self.y, 25, 25)).colliderect(obj)
```